# How to update angular project version 5 for version 7

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

my project is currently at version 5.2 and would like to upgrade to angular version 7.2.15, how to do it the easiest and fastest way, follow my dependencies package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.9",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/icheck": "^0.8.29",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.11.35",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.6.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "icheck": "^1.0.2",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^4.4.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-google-charts": "^3.4.0",
    "ng2-lazy-trumbowyg": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ngx-captcha": "^5.0.4",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.4.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^6.3.8",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "ngx-progressbar": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-uploader": "^7.1.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.2",
    "primeng": "^5.2.3",
    "quill": "^1.3.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "trumbowyg": "^2.15.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.11",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.47",
    "@types/jspdf": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/morris.js": "^0.5.6",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

You can see that is with angular 5 and some dependencies with ng2 -... but this I think you can update the library of each one quietly

I just want to know what I may be changing from the angle to upgrade to version 7.2.15, because I think this is the best time not to break the dependencies too much

Comment: FYI you are in rxjs 5 as you can see, when you move to rxjs6 + there are some breaking changes so besides updating the package.json you will have to update every file where you use rxjs

Answer (score 1):

You will need to follow the angular guide to update from 5 to 7. Unfortunately there is no easy way to update all packages at once. 
In CLI you can use `ng update --packages <list of packages separated by space>`

Take a look at [ng update](https://angular.io/cli/update). However some ng2-... packages from your package.json still may need your attention, as they weren't update for year or two. Hopefully they will support angular 7, but be prepared to replace them with other packages if not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the official website's guide: https://update.angular.io/

Tip: Make sure you update from 5 to 6 and then to 7. Updating from 5 to 7 directly is highly not recommended.